# How to add external js file to my layout page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, layout, scripting

I'm calling external js file to my index.cshtml file to show slider in home page but 3 large image is shown in home page insted of being slides smoothly.

This is a mvc framework project.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/slick.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/nouislider.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery.zoom.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("js/main.js")"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<!-- jQuery Plugins -->
```

I expected three images will  move slide by slide Slide isn't happening its shows three large images  moreover they are not moving

Comment: What's in your `jquery` bundle? Usually one puts, well, jQuery in that. Thus I find it odd that you would include it again right afterwards... Ditto with the `bootstrap` bundle.

Comment: i was searching for similar types of  issues then i found a answer that @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  wil be above of my js file what i want to include. That's why i keep @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") above.  And @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)  below. But actually i have no idea about Render

Comment: Moreover i have added just above of </body> tag. Can't understand why it's not working.

Comment: @Mir, what have you got in App_Start > BundleConfig file ?